# Make data visible to MongoDB in copied files

Tags: mongodb

Sorry if my question is nooby, but I can't find any info about it over the net.

My situation is that I have only three files left from my previous DB (they are db_name.0, db_name.1 and db_name.ns), everything else from that system is lost. The DB version was 1.8 and the files were in /data/db.

Now I have a new DB (which is 2.0) on the new system, so I tried to put them to the new DB path, it seems that DB sees them, but doesn't eat (it doesn't say there's something wrong with DB, but records are nil). I know well there was some data. And I have it in app specs from the customer, so I can type manually this data in new DB again, but I'd like to know if there's a way to make this new DB see the old data in these files (not to do the work that had been done). I restarted mongod, tried mongod --repair — nothing. Is there a way to make MongoDB see these files?

And, now I have two pathes, /data/db and /var/lib/mongodb (which one is right to use?).

Answer (score 0):

> which one is right to use?

There is no "right one". When you start MongoDB, you have to point it to a DB folder by setting the `--dbpath` folder. It can really be any folder you want as long as the user who starts the `mongod` process also has access to that folder.

> Is there a way to make MongoDB see these files?

The files you have listed are the default files created when a new DB is created. MongoDB allocates files *in advance* of needing them. So it's quite possible that these files are indeed empty.

Comment: I know well there was some data. And I have it in app specs from the customer, so I can type manually this data in new DB again, but I'd like to know if there's a way to make this new DB see the old data in these files (for me not to type in again).